# wxPython : Update the label on Panel with GridBagSizer and Timer

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, panel

I want to update the panel "label", but I think I am wrong with Refresh/Update/Remove method .

I write 2 python file, the "WriteData.py" would auto-update a txt file, and the  "Main.py" want to show the txt value on wx.panel.

I run the 2 python file at the same time, use Timer to auto update data every 3 sec .

And I use the GridBagSizer hope to arrange these panel position.

But I don't know how to **arrange the new updating panel position**, Also don't know how to **remove previous panel** .

Hope you give me some advice, or even point out my mistake.
I also appreciate for some example code about this !

Here is the "Main.py"

```
import wx
import time

def ReadData():
    with open('RealTime.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            data = line.split()
    results = map(float, data)
    return results

class BlockWindow(wx.Panel):
    # code on book "wxPython in action" Listing 11.1 
    def __init__(self, parent, ID=-1, label="",
                 pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = (100, 25)):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, 
                          wx.RAISED_BORDER, label)
        self.label = label

        self.SetMinSize(size)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        sz = self.GetClientSize()
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        w,h = dc.GetTextExtent(self.label)
        dc.SetFont(self.GetFont())
        dc.DrawText(self.label, (sz.width-w)/2, (sz.height-h)/2)


class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, size=(0,0))

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(3000)

    def OnTimer(self, evt):
        Data = ReadData()
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(hgap=5, vgap=-1)

        bw = BlockWindow(self, label="Item 1" )
        sizer.Add(bw, pos=(4, 2))
        #bw.Refresh()

        bw = BlockWindow(self, label="Updated : %.3f" % Data[0])
        sizer.Add(bw, pos=(5, 2))
        bw.Refresh()           
        #bw.Update(self, label ="Updated : %.3f" % Data[0] )

        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mainSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)

        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        self.Fit()

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=' Frame Title')
        mypanel = MyPanel(self)
        self.SetSize(wx.Size(800,600))
        self.Centre()

app = wx.App(False)
MyFrame().Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Here is the 'WriteData.py',

```
import sched, time
from datetime import datetime as dt

data = ['5.564', '3.4', '2.176', '7.3',  '4.4', '5.5', '2.3', '4.4', '5.1']

index = 0

while True:
    start = dt.now().hour
    stop = dt.now().hour + 1
    if index >7 : index=1
    if dt.now().hour in range(start, stop):  # start, stop are integers (eg: 6, 9)
        # call to your scheduled task goes here
        f2 = open('RealTime.txt', 'w')
        f2.write("%s " % data[index])
        index = index + 1
        f2.close()

        time.sleep(3)
    else:
        time.sleep(3)
```

When I run the 2 .py file , I got this situation Running example

[image]

Hope you help me solve this .
I use python2.7 on win10.
Best regards, Kuo-Ting Tang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You don't need to recreate everything from scratch** each time an update is needed. Just move the initialization code (where you create `BlockWindow`s and sizers to the constructor of `MyPanel`. It seems that all you want to do is update the label of the second panel, to achieve this you could write a method in `BlockWindow` that will update the label and call `Refresh` so that `OnPaint` will be triggered and will take care of the rest.

```
class BlockWindow(wx.Panel):
    # code on book "wxPython in action" Listing 11.1 
    def __init__(self, parent, ID=-1, label="",
                 pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = (100, 25)):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, 
                          wx.RAISED_BORDER, label)
        self.label = label

        self.SetMinSize(size)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        sz = self.GetClientSize()
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        w,h = dc.GetTextExtent(self.label)
        dc.SetFont(self.GetFont())
        dc.DrawText(self.label, (sz.width-w)/2, (sz.height-h)/2)

    def UpdateLabel(self, label):
        self.label = label
        self.Refresh()

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, size=(0,0))

        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(hgap=5, vgap=-1)
        bw = BlockWindow(self, label="Item 1" )
        sizer.Add(bw, pos=(4, 2))

        self.block = BlockWindow(self, label="")
        sizer.Add(self.block, pos=(5, 2))

        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mainSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 10)

        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        self.Fit()

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(3000)

    def OnTimer(self, evt):
        Data = ReadData()
        self.block.UpdateLabel("Updated : %.3f" % Data[0])
```

Comment: Thank you very much !

Your answer really teach me how to use the Refresh() and Timer correctly, even teach me the way to  improve my BlockWindow .
 
Your code is pretty clean and helpful !